# Connect to Google Plus as a Page / Get pages the user administrates

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I'm trying here to connect with G+ using API. And now there is one big question.

In my code I need to connect to G+ via API and get the posts of G+ Pages. For a user, the API's not giving the authorized user's owned pages. (i.e. in case of Facebook I use `"../me/accounts"` to get my pages and then use the page ID-s to get the public feed)

Is there a way to connect to G+ not as a user, but a page and see the posts? Or is there a way I missed to get user's pages?

**EDIT1:**
Ok, as I learned, it's yet impossible to get user's administered pages. But maybe there is a way to login as a page or something like that? In that case each admin of a page will only need to connect as the page they want to fetch posts from...

Answer (score 0):

[Getting activities](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) for a page is the same as getting them for a person. You just have to specify the ID instead of using the special `me` identifier.

Get the activities for the Google+ page:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/101560853443212199687/activities/public
```

You can see a live example using the [API Explorer](https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1&_m=activities.list&userId=101560853443212199687&collection=public&alt=json).

Comment: to address the other part of the question, we do not currently have a way to get the pages that a given user administers.  You'll need to get the page IDs by some other means, and then use the endpoint Abraham mentioned to fetch the activities.

Comment: @abraham I knew about getting the activities of a page, thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah @Will, that was what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: @WillNorris
How do we get the list of page IDs a user has created / administers?

Comment: @RRMadhav: I don't think that endpoint is publicly available.  It may be in the [Pages API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup), I'm not sure.